# how to make a bootstrap slider responsive in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

im trying to make my slider looks responsive in phones. i have built a web application by Reactjs and bootstrap.

here is my code:

css

```
.carousel{
  width:100%;
    height:500px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .carousel > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
h3{
    color:black;

  }
```

js file:

```
 <Carousel className="carousel">
        <Carousel.Item interval={2000}>
          <img
            className="d-block mx-auto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/4kZFFp9.png"
            alt="First slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item interval={2000}>
          <img
            className="d-block mx-auto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/BuNGcJI.png"
            alt="Second slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item interval={2000}>
          <img
            className="d-block mx-auto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/UDBoRJn.png"
            alt="Third slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
```

i tried to edit both the bootstrap and css file but none of them worked!
any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share a codepen or demo so that the issue can be identified?

Comment: http://fatihacarhome.com.
here it is

Answer (score 0):

Do not fix width and height like that, especially not for phones. Right now you are fixing the height to be the same for all devices. Either handle width, or height. In any case, width:100% is not necessary, it should automatically fill the canvas. If not, then use min-width:100% and height:auto.

You also need to use images that can fill your canvas. Try using images in the ratio 1:1.618:1.

Comment: hello, regarding the size of the photos, can you please give it in pixles or any other measures than ratio?

Comment: For slider images, an example size is 1440x732 (for desktop). In most cases sliders should have 1440p as the width. You can vary your slider height based on your first landing content. Shorter height means the image will not take the whole desktop screen when loaded, and the website will display a portion of the second section of your landing page (which may be useful in some cases).